# How do I search for a pattern using GREP that must occur AFTER the nth occurrence of another pattern on the same line?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file with records that are pipe ('|') delimited. I need to search for a specific string on the 6th column only and then return the entire line through the grep utility. There are totally 10 columns and therefore 9 pipes. In the example lines below, I need to search for 'G50483', Only the 2nd record should be returned.:-

```
3DEAC-9AF7-4EEE-9ACD-A6E376C5727C | 2F6E92EF-8903-4E50-8A6B-7049C0A7543D ||Y| 610535 | DEFERRAL-TASK CLAIMED | RON BOW - ORD  Arv 10-SEP-2015 20:48, BOW-Line 2      Pre-Repair Recurring Deferral Task: Perform a general visual inspection of the transcowl seal P/N 1G50483 every 50FH to ensure no       additional damage is present|| GMT |11-SEP-11

26BDF-D080-4ACC-94F9-1AB39038EBF9 | 2F6E92EF-8903-4E50-8A6B-7049C0A7543D || Y |179808 | DEFERRAL-TASK CLAIMED |RON BOW - ORD  Arv 25-SEP-2015 21:46, BOW-Line 6      Pre-Repair Recurring Deferral Task: Perform a general visual inspection of the transcowl seal P/N G50483 every 50FH to ensure no        additional damage is present || GMT | 27-SEP-10

G50483 26B2F1DF-D080-4ACC-94F9-1AB39038EBF9 | 2F6E92EF-8903-4E50-8A6B-7049C0A7543D || Y |179808 | DEFERRAL-TASK CLAIMED | RON BOW - ORD  Arv 25-SEP-2015 21:46, BOW-Line 6       Pre-Repair Recurring Deferral Task: Perform a general visual inspection of the transcowl seal P/N 3G50483 every 50FH to ensure no       additional damage is present|| GMT | 27-SEP-05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be `grep`:

```
grep -Em2 "([^|]+|){6}[^|]+G50483.*' file | tail -n1
```

- `-E` activates extended regular expressions
- `-m2` stops at the second match
- `'...'` the regular expression

  - `[^|]+|` searches for one or more (`+`) character which are not a pipe `|` followed by a pipe.
  - `(...){6}` this is done 6 times consecutively, so we are in the 7th field now. Your question mentions the 6th field, but I assumed the 7th field because of the example input. Change it to `{5}` if desired.
  - `[^|]+` now we again search for characters which are not pipes until the final search patter:
  - `G50483` the actual pattern
- `tail -n1` is necessary, because `grep` alone cannot print only the nth occurence, `tail` cuts the other occurence that only the 2nd one appreas.

Comment: Works perfectly and thanks a ton for the detailed explanation. It's crystal clear and very educative!

Answer (score 0):

In Unix you need to pick the right tool for the job since it provides you with a toolkit. *grep* works on whole lines. Use awk instead:

```
awk -F "|" '$6 ~ /G50483/ { print $2; }'
```

- `-F` is the field seperator "|" in this case
- `$6` is the column to search pattern
- `~` matches a pattern (you can use == for an exact match)
- `/pattern/` search pattern
- `$2` - 2nd field (`$0` would be all line)

More info here:*Effective AWK Programming - 4e*.

Comment: I think OP want 2nd field, and separator is pipe, not colon. awk -F\| '$6 ~ /G50483/ { print $2; }'

Comment: yeah, wanted him to read vs cut and paste

Comment: The solution works perfectly! Thank you very much for this alternate solution. The explanation is also very educative.